# Robocopy script to retrieve documents

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have the following batch file that connects to a network drive and retrieves a list of documents contained in the `e:\cn_documents.csv` file to the `e:\data` directory and any files it can't find it sticks it in the `doesnotexist.csv` file.

The problem with the batch job is it took 20 hours to retrieve 200000 documents. I was told that Robocopy would be quicker. Would anyone have a robocopy script that would do the same?

```
@echo off
net use \\10.10.10.1\ipc$ /d
net use \\10.10.10.1\ipc$ /user:company\joebloggs Password1
SET destfolder=e:\data
SET DoesNotExistList="E:\DoesNotExist_CN.txt"

REM Reset the not exist list so it doesn't pile up from multiple runs.
ECHO The following Contract Note files were not found > %DoesNotExistList%

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (e:\cn_documents.csv) DO (
    REM Check if the file exists.
    IF EXIST "%%a" (
        REM It does exist, copy to the destination.
        COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
    ) ELSE (
        REM It does not exist, note the file name.
        ECHO %%a>>%DoesNotExistList%
    )
)
```

Comment: RoboCopy is good for bulk operations, it would not be faster than `copy` when you have to call it once for each file.

Comment: The machine I'm copying from doesn't have a ftp service, so I can't use that. Any other ideas?